# AWS ec2 instance becomes unresponsive after I/O heavy operation in dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm using free tier ec2-instance (t2.micro) with EBS volume (default one). I use a docker container to host a website.

Occasionally, when I run out of storage, I have to bulk delete my dangling docker images. On performing delete and rebuilding the container ssh instance hangs (while installing the npm modules), and I'm not able to even log into my machine for almost 1-2 hours.

On research, I realized this has something to do with burst credits, but on inspecting my EBS burst credits I still have 60 credits left. And I have around 90 CPU credits.

Not sure why this unresponsiveness in happening, my instance even stops serving the website it's running after this for 1-2 hours.

For reference, [this](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/production/django/Dockerfile) is my Dockerfile.

Comment: The [gp2 EBS volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html#EBSVolumeTypes_gp2) has its own credit-based performance throttling system, and it sounds like you might be running into that.  Is your application otherwise particularly disk-intensive?

Comment: I see, @DavidMaze my application isn't disk-intensive otherwise, I face this issue only preiodically when I run out of disk space and I have to clean up the docker images.